# do_settings_sections() doesn't escape quotes

Tags: settings-api, encoding

I'm using the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) on a custom settings page:

```
<form action='options.php' method='post'>
    <?php
    settings_fields('myplugin_settingsPage');
    do_settings_sections('myplugin_settingsPage' );
    submit_button();
    ?>
</form>
```

It's a very simple simple settings page, with a few text input fields. The problem is, some of the fields' values contain double quotes (for example, `Jhon "cracy" Garcia`), and it seems Wordpress doesn't escape this character. The value stored in the database seems ok, I've checked it. But, when you visit the settings page a second time, this is the HTML generated by Wordpress:

```
<input name='myplugin_settingsPage[name]' value="Jhon "cracy" Garcia" size=40>
```

As you can see, the quotes aren't being urlencoded so the generated HTML is broken. Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. You need to escape the values in the _render functions, using [`esc_attr`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr), like this:

```
function my_setting_render() {
    $options = get_option('my_option_name');
    ?><input name='my_option_name[my_setting]' value="<?php echo esc_attr($options['my_setting']);?>">
    <?php
```

}